# Display custom fields only if it has a value

Tags: custom-field

I've setup standard custom fields for some products in WooCommerce which are being displayed on each product page on the front end. However, I'd like to hide those fields that don't have a value entered. I've tried some suggestions made elsewhere on this site but they didn't work for me.

This is what I have on the description.php

```
<div id="customfield-meta">
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>Catalogue Number: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'catalogue', true )."</li>";
echo "<li>License Type: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'license', true )."</li>";
echo "<li>Width (px): ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'iswidth', true )."</li>";
echo "<li>Height (px): ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'isheight', true )."</li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
</div> <!-- end #customfield-meta -->
```

Any ideas how I could do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isset() function to check if it has a value.

In your case you can do like this :

```
    $width = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'iswidth', true );
    if( isset( $width ) ){
      echo "<li>Width (px): ".$width."</li>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I must be doing something wrong because it didn't work. I tried replacing this line with your suggestion - echo "<li>Width (px): ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'iswidth', true )."</li>";

Comment: Try `! empty( $width )` instead. @kamala

Comment: var_dump( $width ); //To check the value

Comment: Thanks ialocin, the ! empty works. I just have one other custom field that I can't get right. It pulls a link from the field entry so users can download a file. I tried this code but it doesn't work; $comp = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'comp', true );
    if( ! empty( $comp ) ){
      echo "<li><a href="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'comp', true ) . '">Download Video Comp</a> (right-click/save link or target as) ".$comp."</li>";

Comment: A simple `if( $width )` works too ;)